# Using MS Access Online

Tags: ms-access, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-storage, google-chrome-app

I know  this is shot in the dark.  I also know that using Access as an online DB is not the best idea.  But, my hands are a bit tied in this regard.  I want to know if there is a way to use Microsoft Access as a Database, online.  It would be stored in Google Cloud.  I would then create a Google App or Google Site to do CRUD actions against the db.  Is this possible?  If so, can someone provide a proof on concept with connecting to a db like this?

Essentially, I need to have an online DB, with the following constraints:

1. I cannot host outside of what is approved.  Google Drive is the only online storage area that is approved
2. The only storage apps that are allowed would be Access, Excel, and any google doc (like Google Sheets).
3. I cannot use Google Cloud SQL, as that is not approved.
4. This would only be the backend storage.  I would use Google Chrome App or Google site to be the front end.
5. I can use Chrome Apps (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app) and App Scripts (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/)
   Any ideas?

thanks

thanks

Comment: You can map a folder to a Google Drive and store the database there, but I'm not sure how you plan on building a front-end without using MS-Access. Are you thinking about using PHP from a website? There's many better alternatives than what you're attempting

Comment: Hi, I would love to hear alternatives.  But, as I cannot host an app, I'm not sure what options I would have.  Without a server, I can't use server languages (i.e.PHP)  I planned on using Google Chrome Apps (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app)  and, possibly, App Scripts (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) for my front end

Comment: Use Google Apps with Google Sheets - your app can't be too intensive if you have such stringent limitations. Learning curve is going to be steep and functionality limited.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that.  But, the overhead needed to re-create all the functionality of a database would be prohibitive, with respect to cost and time.  The data is not sensitive, but it does use common DB practices (like unique identifiers, different relationship types, different data types).  Recreating all of this would not really be worth the effort.

Comment: Building front end as per your spec is not trivial ==> *I would use Google Chrome App or Google site to be the front end.*

Comment: FYI, Chrome apps are deprecated and in a couple of years won't run on Chrome [[announcement](http://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html)].

Comment: That is good to know.  thanks

Comment: Are you able to use [Google Fusion Tables](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2571232?hl=en)? They are *kind of* like a database. certainly better than Sheets and way better than use an Access DB from Google Drive (not sure how you'd read/write to it).

Comment: No, our CIO apparently disabled that "We are sorry, but you do not have access to this service. Please contact your domain administrator for access."

Answer (score 1):

To actually have MS Access running in the cloud would require a Google Compute Engine instance running Windows Server, which seems like it would also be blocked for you given your list of constraints. You mentioned that recreating the functionality of a database would be prohibitive, but that's exactly what you need to do if you can't actually run Access.

This means your only option is to work with an export of the database data, such as to an Excel file, CSV, Google Sheet etc. You'd need to host the export on drive, since as you mention it's the only online storage area that's approved.

[Google Sites](https://sites.google.com/) with [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) is probably the best choice, as Apps Script is tailored to Sites and has built in APIs for [Drive](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/) and [Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/). Alternatively you could export to Excel if it would retain more information, but you'd be stuck with parsing it manually in JavaScript.